# Does ionisation by impact cause the emission of light?

Tags: visible-light

An electron strikes an atom/molecule at ground state and that impact causes an electron to be lost (ionisation). Does this process cause the emission of light?

Comment: It certainly could leave the ion in an excited state, sure.

Comment: Yes, and you can also do it in the solid state, for example in electroluminescent device you can have an electron accelerate within the material and ionize an atom and have it produce light.

Comment: You don’t even need the atom/molecule. Just accelerate the electron and photons will be emitted from it.

Answer (score 0):

Usually there are many eleectrons arounfdwhich will take this place, so light will be emitted. If you had an isolated atom or molecule, nothing around, no light will be emitted before this atom meets an electron.

Answer (score 0):

> An electron strikes an atom/molecule at ground state and that impact causes an electron to be lost (ionization).

> Does this process cause the emission of light?

Yes, generally it can.

For example, suppose the electron that is lost is a deep core electron (e.g., "1s" type electron). That core hole "wants" to be filled by another electron. The other available electrons that can fill the hole are in higher energy orbitals (e.g., "2p" type electron). As the electron transitions from a higher energy orbital to a lower energy orbital it emits a photon (light). Such a "2p" to "1s" type transition results in the [Lyman alpha series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lyman_series). Similarly "2d" to "1s" are called Lyman-beta.

If the electron that is initially ejected is a different sort of core electron (e.g., "2s") then the emission lines have a different name (e.g., [Balmer series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Balmer_series) instead of Lyman series).

Comment: How likely when a free electron, of sufficient energy, hits a ground state atom/molecule will reach the "deep core electron" in order to release it? Isn't it supposed that the outmost electrons are more loosely held? In such case, when one outermost electron is lost, we will have a positive ion created. Then another free electron is likely to be attached to the positive ion to bring the atom/molecule back to its ground state, am I correct?

Comment: @user3212953 With sufficient exciting electron energy, the lines from K shell vacancies can be very prominent: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X-ray_tube#/media/File:TubeSpectrum.jpg

Comment: @user3212953 the likelihood can be calculated, for example, using Fermi's golden rule. It certainly depends on the incident electron energy as well as the target atom (or solid) properties. But, you can kick out core electrons via bombardment with other electrons. This is the basis of certain aspects of the spectroscopy known as "EELS" (Electron Energy Loss Spectra). However, I think it is easier to do this kind core-level spectroscopy with x-rays probes rather than electrons (basically just because electrons interact super strongly with all the sample electrons)

Comment: @hft ...I see. I have to familirise myself with this principle. Although my thought was not that much into the X-ray range of applications. For example, in atmospheric air there is certain number of electrons that move freely. Once we apply an electric field we will accelarate them so that they will strike neutral molecules of O2/N2. If there is light emitted, very likely >185-200nm, where does this come from?

Comment: @user3212953 185nm correspond to a photon energy of about 6.7 eV. This is a typical atomic electron energy scale. The emission is likely of the kind I was describing in my answer--probably due to an electron dropping into either the oxygen or the nitrogen "K shell" (1s hole). For those tightly bound core electrons the molecular structure isn't super important. So you can look up the atomic spectra for Oxygen and Nitrogen. Also, there is an article available regarding the N2 molecule spectra here: https://srd.nist.gov/JPCRD/jpcrd93.pdf